# How to delete backward word in find-file using ido?

Tags: find-file, ido

I was using regular `find-file`, and have a current setup to delete a word, which was working inside `find-file`.

```
(defun backward-delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters backward until encountering the beginning of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-region (point) (progn (backward-word arg) (point))))

(global-set-key "\C-o" 'backward-delete-word)
```

---

When I switch to `ido` via `(ido-mode 1)` word deletion does not work in ido-find-file minibuffer.

**[Q]** Is there any way to do backward word deletion in `ido-find-file`?

Comment: try using `M-backspace` or `M-DEL` to delete words backward. It's bound to `backward-kill-word`

Comment: Is there any way to do it with different key-binding such as `\C-o`?

Comment: sure, just add one with `define-key` or `global-set-key` depending your goals. Be careful with global bindings.

Comment: I set `\C-o` for it as (`(global-set-key "\C-o" 'backward-kill-word)
`); but `ido` sees it as TAB

Comment: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-o") 'backward-kill-word)`

Comment: it does not work as well, probably ido overwrites it

Comment: To make it work only with Ido you should add them in the ido setup hook. Check Ido Customization in the manual for more info.

Comment: https://github.com/danskarda/ido-mode-el/blob/c95837d0f0b5d5c5a738418f493d10ce2fb0ed68/ido.el#L1636

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was conflicting with `ido`'s keybinding so I disabled it.

```
(defun bind-ido-keys ()
  "Keybindings for ido mode."
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "\C-o") 'nil))

(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook #'bind-ido-keys)
```